# How to access node value for testing form in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a form in react with a cancel button which literally just sets all the values back to "" again:

This is an example of one of the input fields in the form:

```
 <Input
    type="text"
    onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
    value={firstName}
    data-testid="name-input"
 />
```

This is the cancel button and function:

```
 const cancelForm = () => {
    setFirstName("");
 };

<CancelButton data-testid="cancel-form" onClick={cancelForm}>
   Cancel
</CancelButton>
```

This is my test so far:

```
test("pressing cancel clears form fields", async () => {
  render(<App />);

  const firstNameInput = screen.getByTestId("name-input");
  const cancelForm = screen.getByTestId("cancel-form");

  fireEvent.change(firstNameInput, { target: { value: "Bob" } });
  console.error(firstNameInput);

  fireEvent.click(cancelForm);

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(firstNameInput.childNodes[0].textContent).toEqual("");
  });
});
```

When I console.error I can see there is something there which has the value of 'Bob', so that has worked. However, I'm unsure how to access it. This is what the `console.error` snippet looks like:

```
 },
    '__reactProps$en230471ca': {
    type: 'text',
    onChange: [Function: onChange],
    value: 'Bob',
    'data-testid': 'name-input',
    className: 'sc-gsnTZi oioMi'
 },
```

My question is how can I access that `value` property? I'm sure I've done it similarly in the past doing `childNodes[0].textContent` or `nodeValue` but neither of these work, saying it can't read this of `undefined`?

Comment: it should be ```expect(firstNameInput.value).toEqual("");```, right ??

Comment: @bogdanoff this gives the error `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts`

Comment: ```const firstNameInput = screen.getByTestId("name-input") as HTMLInputElement ;``` should fix that